# Merging Start and durations with timeslots

Tags: c#, time, merge

I have a data file containing several TV broadcasts with their start and duration time in minutes, and I have to merge it with another file containing some 2 hours timeslot.
Here's a sample of what it looks like:

File1:

1. date      |start   |duration
2. 19/05/2014|15:25:00|55
3. 19/05/2014|16:20:00|30
4. 19/05/2014|16:50:00|25
5. 19/05/2014|17:15:00|55
6. 19/05/2014|18:10:00|30

File2:

1. timeslot     |timeslot_info
2. 05:00 - 07:00|info_to_merge
3. 07:00 - 09:00|info_to_merge
4. 09:00 - 11:00|info_to_merge
5. 11:00 - 13:00|info_to_merge
6. 13:00 - 15:00|info_to_merge
7. 15:00 - 17:00|info_to_merge
8. 17:00 - 19:00|info_to_merge
9. 19:00 - 21:00|info_to_merge
10. 21:00 - 23:00|info_to_merge
11. 23:00 - 25:00|info_to_merge
12. 25:00 - 27:00|info_to_merge
13. 27:00 - 29:00|info_to_merge

Now what I have to do is, for each occurrence of file 1, find the timeslot of the file 2 corresponding following those rules:
- The timeslot in which the occurrence is "the most included" into has to be selected
- If the occurrence covers more than one timeslot entirely, the last entirely covered timeslot should be selected

I've tried a lot of heavy codes, but I couldn't find how to deduce the correct timeslot..
I figured a logic where I'm browsing each occurrence of the first file and try to assign it a timeslot key for further matching but no more:

```
private string GetTimeSlot(string line)
{
    string result = "";

    string[] tab = line.Split('\t');
    string start = tab[LogsStartTimeColumnIndex];
    string[] starttab = start.Split(':');

    TimeSpan StartTime = new TimeSpan(Int32.Parse(starttab[0]), Int32.Parse(starttab[1]), Int32.Parse(starttab[2]));
    TimeSpan Duration = new TimeSpan(0, Int32.Parse(tab[LogsDurationColumnIndex], 0), 0);
    TimeSpan EndTime = StartTime + Duration;


    //don't know how to do it from here..

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to separate the parsing of the input data files, from the logic that finds the required Timeslot.

In terms of the logic to find the correct Timeslot, you could use the following as a start. It implements the logic you have detailed above ie "The timeslot in which the occurrence is "the most included" into has to be selected - If the occurrence covers more than one timeslot entirely, the last entirely covered timeslot should be selected":

**UPDATED - to support the 'night' timeslots** I have introduced a `TimeInHours` class to represent what the `Timespan` was previously doing

```
public class TimeslotsFinder
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Timeslot> _allTimeslots;

    public TimeslotsFinder(IEnumerable<Timeslot> allTimeslots)
    {
        _allTimeslots = allTimeslots;
    }

    public Timeslot FindTimeslot(Broadcast broadcast)
    {
        var found = _allTimeslots
            .Select(t => new { Timeslot = t, DurationInTimeslot = DurationInTimeslot(broadcast, t) })
            .Where(x => x.DurationInTimeslot > TimeInHours.Zero)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DurationInTimeslot.Value)
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.Timeslot.Start.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return found == null ? null : found.Timeslot;
    }

    private static TimeInHours DurationInTimeslot(Broadcast broadcast, Timeslot timeslot)
    {
        if (!(InTimeslot(broadcast, timeslot) || CoversEntireTimeslot(broadcast, timeslot))) return TimeInHours.Zero;

        var endToUse = broadcast.EndTime >= timeslot.End
                        ? timeslot.End
                        : broadcast.EndTime;

        var startToUse = broadcast.StartTime <= timeslot.Start
                        ? timeslot.Start
                        : broadcast.StartTime;

        return endToUse.Subtract(startToUse);
    }

    private static bool InTimeslot(Broadcast broadcast, Timeslot timeslot)
    {
        var startsInTimeslot = timeslot.Start <= broadcast.StartTime && broadcast.StartTime < timeslot.End;
        var endsInTimeslot = timeslot.End < broadcast.EndTime && broadcast.EndTime <= timeslot.End;

        return startsInTimeslot || endsInTimeslot;
    }

    private static bool CoversEntireTimeslot(Broadcast broadcast, Timeslot timeslot)
    {
        return broadcast.StartTime <= timeslot.Start && broadcast.EndTime >= timeslot.End;
    }
}
```

The logic above obviously uses these classes:

**These have also been updated to use the TimeInHours class**

```
public class Broadcast
{
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

    public TimeInHours StartTime
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeInHours.FromTimeSpan(StartDateTime.TimeOfDay);
        }
    }

    public TimeInHours EndTime
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeInHours.FromTimeSpan(StartDateTime.Add(Duration).TimeOfDay);
        }
    }
}

public class Timeslot
{
    public TimeInHours Start { get; set; }
    public TimeInHours End { get; set; }

    public TimeInHours Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return End.Subtract(Start);
        }
    }
}

public class TimeInHours
{
    public TimeInHours(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public TimeInHours Subtract(TimeInHours x)
    {
        return new TimeInHours(Value - x.Value);
    }

    public static TimeInHours FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        return new TimeInHours(ts.Hours);
    }

    public static TimeInHours Zero
    {
        get
        {
            return new TimeInHours(0);
        }
    }

    public static bool operator < (TimeInHours t1, TimeInHours t2)
    {
        return t1.Value < t2.Value;
    }

    public static bool operator >(TimeInHours t1, TimeInHours t2)
    {
        return t1.Value > t2.Value;
    }

    public static bool operator <=(TimeInHours t1, TimeInHours t2)
    {
        return t1.Value <= t2.Value;
    }

    public static bool operator >=(TimeInHours t1, TimeInHours t2)
    {
        return t1.Value >= t2.Value;
    }
}
```

You can test this logic with something like this:

**Also updated to use the TimeInHours class**

```
        var timeslots = new List<Timeslot>
        {
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(5), End = new TimeInHours(7)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(7), End = new TimeInHours(9)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(9), End = new TimeInHours(11)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(11), End = new TimeInHours(13)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(13), End = new TimeInHours(15)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(15), End = new TimeInHours(17)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(17), End = new TimeInHours(19)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(19), End = new TimeInHours(21)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(21), End = new TimeInHours(23)},
            new Timeslot{Start = new TimeInHours(23), End = new TimeInHours(25)},
        };

        var finder = new TimeslotsFinder(timeslots);

        var broadcast = new Broadcast { StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("19/05/2014 09:00"), Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(250) };
        var timeslot = finder.FindTimeslot(broadcast);
```

With this logic in place, it should then just be matter of parsing the data files to create the required `Broadcast` and `Timeslot` instances. I will leave this part to you as I believe it will beneficial for you to create the parsing code yourself.

Comment: Indeed, I already got the parsing code working on my side, I just couldn't figure out the logic to find the right timeslot. I will need some time to understand your code, but I'm on it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're very welcome, let me know how you go and please accept the answer if it does the trick for you.

Comment: Ok so, it's partially working.. But I can't see how I can include the night timeslot covering 23:00 -> 25:00 since this format is not accepted (25:00 is not recognized as a correct timespan). And if I add the following timeslot to the list: new Timeslot{Start = TimeSpan.Parse("23:00"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("01:00")}, it will have no sense as the start time is bigger than the end time ?

Comment: OK, looks like we will have to replace the use of the `TimeSpan` with something else. Give me a couple of minutes and I will post an update.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reactivity :) You're saving my day.. I tried something like: new Timeslot{Start = new TimeSpan(0,23,0,0), End = new TimeSpan(1,1,0,0)}, but it doesn't seem to be selected for any broadcast